# How to change image labels in Prestashop 1.6 via webservices?

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a Prestashop 1.6 module for creating a product in a remote Prestashop via WebServices. Now I can create images without problems, but I cannot figure out how to change their labels.
In the database there is a table named images_lang but which resource should I use for adding records to it?

```php
$url = $ps_url . '/api/images/products/' . $product_id;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data','Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ps_key.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => new CurlFile($image_path)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(FALSE === $result){
    $output->errors[] = 'Unable to create remote image';
} else {
    //here I should update image label
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Can you help?